# Does any equation holds for inverse(A- B)?

Tags: matrix, algebra, equations, matrix-inverse

is it possible to calculate inverse of A-B, i have calculated inverse of A and B already.

Comment: This is not really on-topic for stackoverflow. Try http://math.stackexchange.com/. BTW, I suspect the answer is that knowing the inverses of A and B doesn't help you find the inverse of A-B.

Answer (score 2):

No, the inverse of A-B is not a nice function of the inverses of A and B. (Of course it's *possible* to calculate -- if you have the inverses of A and B then you can calculate A and B, hence A-B, hence the inverse of A-B -- but, assuming you knew A and B anyway, knowing their inverses too doesn't help you calculate A-B more efficiently or accurately.)

There are some special cases where you *can* do something useful. For instance, if one of the matrices has rank 1 then this is basically the Sherman-Morrison formula. But in general you're out of luck.